# MIPS: Does a load word create a data hazard if an instruction loads from the same register?

Tags: mips, instructions

Does a load word create a data hazard if a subsequent instruction loads from the same register?
I have

```
lw $t0 0($t1)
addi $s0, $t1, 4
```

Would this create a data hazard, since you need what is stored in the register for both operations? What if the instructions are reversed or there is an offset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In general, register reads do not create hazards. In this case if `$t1` was read by the `lw`, then it can be read by the next instruction without a pipeline stall/hazard.